# Is there a way to change VIM's EasyMotion plugin so it displays 2 instead of 1 charactere for multiple matched keys?

Tags: vim, plugins, shortcut, vimperator

I know this question is harder than usual, but is there a way to change VIM's EasyMotion plugin so it displays 2 characteres when searching for a character that has too many matchess, like FireFox's Vimperator does? The default behavior is showing 1 character, waiting for you to press it and then showing the other.

EasyMotion: shows 1 caractere when multiple matches (notice the multiple red 'z')
[EasyMotion: shows 1 caractere when multiple matches http://o7.no/P313g7](http://o7.no/P313g7)

Vimperator: shows 2 characteres
[Vimperator: shows 2 characteres http://o7.no/QOfwIE](http://o7.no/QOfwIE)

Comment: Vim plugins are not compiled or proprietary: the whole source is available to you so you can do whatever you want with them. Did you look at the code? Did you ask the developer?

Comment: Took a quick look at the plugin and it looks like it provides two different algorithms that group the targets differently but I don't see a way to do what you ask.  I would suggest opening a feature request if one doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this fork uses vimperator style 2-key combos:

https://github.com/skwp/vim-easymotion